# Replacing a 'total' tag with an 'other' tag by taking the difference from rows in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
 account     region     measure     value     date
 acct1       USA        Expense     100       1/31/2019
 acct1       USA        Sales       150       1/31/2019
 acct2       USA        Expense     1000      1/31/2019
 acct2       USA        Sales       1500      1/31/2019
 acct2       East       Expense     500       1/31/2019
 acct2       East       Sales       800       1/31/2019
 acct1       West       Expense     90        1/31/2019
 acct1       West       Sales       140       1/31/2019
 acct2       West       Expense     450       1/31/2019
 acct2       West       Sales       500       1/31/2019
```

There are accounts and regions associated with dates, measures, and values.

Even though the USA region tag is meant to be a total, the east and west regions do not necessarily add up to the total USA. My goal is to change the "USA" rows to an "Other" tag that allows the now three region to aggregate to the previous "USA" numbers.

So, it would look like the following:

```
 account     region     measure     value     date
 acct1       Other      Expense     10        1/31/2019
 acct1       Other      Sales       10        1/31/2019
 acct2       Other      Expense     50        1/31/2019
 acct2       Other      Sales       200       1/31/2019
 acct2       East       Expense     500       1/31/2019
 acct2       East       Sales       800       1/31/2019
 acct1       West       Expense     90        1/31/2019
 acct1       West       Sales       140       1/31/2019
 acct2       West       Expense     450       1/31/2019
 acct2       West       Sales       500       1/31/2019
```

As you can see, the "East" and "West" regions have not changes, and all three sum up to the "USA" totals before.

I have tried a number of different way of achieving this to no avail. First, I tried breaking out three dfs for each region:

```
 df_usa = df[df['region'] == 'USA']
 df_east = df[df['region'] == 'east']
 df_west = df[df['region'] == 'west']
```

Then creating an "other" df and subtracting based on column:

```
 df_usa['value'] = df_usa['value'] - df_east['value'] - df_west['value']
```

This does not work since each regional df has a different number of accounts/rows. I would also need to account for additional dates in the dataset.

As I'm sure you can tell, I'm still new to pandas computations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little easier to work with your data if you do a little bit of reshaping. First, moving the identifying elements to an index and the regions to columns makes it clearer what goes with what:

```
In [46]: regions = df.set_index(["account", "region", "measure", "date"]).sort_index().unstack(1)

In [47]: regions.columns = regions.columns.droplevel()

In [48]: regions
Out[48]:
region                      East     USA   West
account measure date
acct1   Expense 1/31/2019    NaN   100.0   90.0
        Sales   1/31/2019    NaN   150.0  140.0
acct2   Expense 1/31/2019  500.0  1000.0  450.0
        Sales   1/31/2019  800.0  1500.0  500.0
```

In this shape, it's easy enough to create the other field:

```
In [49]: regions['Other'] = (regions['USA'] * 2) - regions.sum(axis=1)

In [50]: regions
Out[50]:
region                      East     USA   West  Other
account measure date
acct1   Expense 1/31/2019    NaN   100.0   90.0   10.0
        Sales   1/31/2019    NaN   150.0  140.0   10.0
acct2   Expense 1/31/2019  500.0  1000.0  450.0   50.0
        Sales   1/31/2019  800.0  1500.0  500.0  200.0
```

You could then continue to work with it in this format, or you can restack things to get back to the original form:

```
In [51]: regions.drop("USA", axis=1).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'value'})
Out[51]:
  account  measure       date region  value
0   acct1  Expense  1/31/2019   West   90.0
1   acct1  Expense  1/31/2019  Other   10.0
2   acct1    Sales  1/31/2019   West  140.0
3   acct1    Sales  1/31/2019  Other   10.0
4   acct2  Expense  1/31/2019   East  500.0
5   acct2  Expense  1/31/2019   West  450.0
6   acct2  Expense  1/31/2019  Other   50.0
7   acct2    Sales  1/31/2019   East  800.0
8   acct2    Sales  1/31/2019   West  500.0
9   acct2    Sales  1/31/2019  Other  200.0
```

Comment: unfortunately my data is not perfectly clean, and there are instances where i can have multiple entries for one set of account, region, measure, and date. for this reason, I'm getting a "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" whenever I try running your first step. could I use a groupby method to aggregate the multiple entries?

Comment: Yeah, you could do a `.groupby(...).first()` if they're just duplicate entries. I'd recommend double checking that you don't have conflicting values for them though.

Comment: you're right, my mistake - the values of the "duplicate" rows would still need to be aggregated (duplicate was definitely not the right choice of word). Does that mean i just need to do a .groupby(...).sum()?

Comment: Yep, that will give you a single aggregated row for them.